# Add a link to moderator tools to the new review dropdown menu

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, review-queues, top-bar, 10k-tools

Could we get a link to https://stackoverflow.com/tools in the new review dropdown menu? Only for >10k users obviously.

I'll admit I'm lazy (remember, this is a [virtue](http://threevirtues.com/)): the new UI now requires 3 clicks to get there (Review -> All Queues -> Tools).

I think that adding a gray header like in the other three menus would be nice for consistency, and it would make some room for the link. Also, notice there's already a "loading" header which disappears once the queues info is shown.

Here's a mockup:

[image: Review header]

Comment: Could we get the queue limits displayed as well? Like **191/200** for Suggested Edits.

Comment: Good point with consistency.

Comment: The 10k /tools page is called "Moderator tools" on the privs page and "Moderation tools" on the actual page. What is the correct name? :/

Comment: @BhargavRao looks like this one is `status-completed` \o/

Answer (score 12):

Here's a quickly written userscript that inserts the header and link:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name       addHeader
// @namespace  http://example.com/
// @version    0.1
// @description  enter something useful
// @match      http://stackoverflow.com/*
// @match      http://meta.stackoverflow.com/*
// @match      https://stackoverflow.com/*
// @match      https://meta.stackoverflow.com/*
// @copyright  2017+, You
// ==/UserScript==

function exec(fn) {
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.setAttribute("type", "application/javascript");
    script.textContent = '(' + fn + ')();';
    document.body.appendChild(script);
    document.body.removeChild(script);
}

window.addEventListener("load", function () {
    exec(function () {
        let inserted = false;
        function addHeader() {
            if (! inserted) {
                setTimeout(() => {
                    let header = document.createElement('div');
                    header.innerHTML = `<div class="header">
                            <h3>Review</h3>
                            <span class="pull-right"><a href="//stackoverflow.com/tools">tools</a></span>
                        </div>`;
                    let element = document.querySelector('div.review-dialog');
                    element.insertBefore(header, element.childNodes[0]);
                }, 1000);

                inserted = true;
            }
        }

        document.querySelector(`li > a[href="/review"]`).addEventListener('click', addHeader);
    });
}, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

The following userscript is a bit simpler than the previously submitted userscript. It should also have less chance of failing or having visual incongruity caused by the timeout in the other script. This script piggybacks the AJAX call that populates the dialog.

([GitHub](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/a7639ab89ad57c7456f94326bb2f7c20) / [Install](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/a7639ab89ad57c7456f94326bb2f7c20/raw/c144af52cdc1faf08dd047b13ee77b4caf7e20ab/SOTopbarReviewDialogTools.user.js))

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         SO Topbar Review Dialog Tools
// @namespace    http://tinygiant.io
// @version      1.0.0.0
// @description  Adds a header with a link to the moderator tools in the new topbar review menu
// @author       @TinyGiant
// @include      /^https?:\/\/(?!chat)\w*.?(stackexchange.com|stackoverflow.com|serverfault.com|superuser.com|askubuntu.com|stackapps.com|mathoverflow.net)\/.*/
// @grant        none
// ==/UserScript==
/* jshint esnext: true */

(function() {
  'use strict';

  const open = XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open;

  XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open = function(...args)  {
    this.addEventListener('load', event => {
      if(!/topbar\/review/.test(event.target.responseURL)) return;
      document.querySelector('.review-dialog').insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', `
        <div class="header">
          <h3>Review</h3>
          <span class="pull-right"><a href="//stackoverflow.com/tools">tools</a></span>
        </div>
      `);
    }, false);
    open.apply(this, args);
  };
})();
```