# The new review icon isn't an improvement

Tags: discussion, design

TylerH mentioned [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/355233/621962) that he likes the new review icon (currently in A/B testing):

[image: new review icon, now with twice as many cryptic UI cues]

That icon is the same, isn't it? For pity's sake, can we replace that icon or [just add some text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/351081/4660897)?

Now it has a red dot. Great. Even the red dot's meaning isn't clear; there's no way to infer [its actual meaning](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/355234/621962) from the UI. I can only assume it means:

> Hey, something's up with the stapler chat bubble thing! Office supply threat level: cabernet?

**What is so wrong with text that we're clinging to such cryptic UI cues?**

Comment: [Your hybrid suggestion](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/351081/4660897) received almost 250 upvotes and was clearly a good idea. I don't what is stopping them from implementing it.

Comment: @TotZam It probably is a victim of its environment - it's posted as an answer to a feature-request, and the feature-request never got an official response (just some comments). So it's easy to miss/ignore in that form, is my guess.

Comment: @TylerH I'd agree with you except I'm pretty sure Shog already talked to the team about that.

Comment: I don't understand. Doesn't the free hand red circle makes it clear for people where to look?

Comment: @rene It's not freehand.  It's also the wrong shade of red.  That's why it won't work.

Comment: @Servy rene's making a joke about my FHRC... as if it were part of the new UI.

Comment: I have no idea what the red and grey circles mean. There are no tooltips to explain them to me. It's all super confusing.

Comment: Hmm, looks like circles have replaced where numbers used to be. I guess [the numbers got too big again and were intimidating people](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252572/fuzzy-the-number-of-questions-in-the-close-review-queue-a-dopamine-for-the-shut). Circles are much friendlier, at the cost of being entirely opaque. This is not a step in the right direction. The close vote queue is *out of control*, and has been for some time. A red circle is not going to solve that problem.

Comment: I'm sure this has been answered elsewhere, but I can't find it.  In what way is that icon supposed to represent "review queue".

Comment: It is *an* improvement in that the red spot actually focuses attention. But I agree that its meaning is not clear at all.

Comment: @TotZam It is worth noting that the meta effect seems to work on meta posts as well. The proposal is now up to 320 upvotes.

Answer (score 34):

First, I gotta say that I *love* [your mock-up](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/350836/please-change-the-review-icon-back-to-a-text-link/351081#351081), and so does just about everyone else I've talked to; it's a very clean, elegant look that neither depends on nor eschews the value of text for communicating function. Ultimately, the decision of whether or not to use it or something like it rests with [our design team](https://stackoverflow.com/company/team#Design).

In the meantime, we're left to grapple with the question of what to do about reviews not getting done.

The nice thing about even an utterly cryptic icon is that *eventually* folks do get used to it. Or they disappear and are replaced by a new generation who just assume it means something to the old folks who they're replacing. In this case, that process took about 5 months, which was really painful and something I didn't want to do. But regardless, here's where we are today:

[image: more active reviewers than ever!]

That looks awesome, right? More active reviewers than *ever!* Well...

[image: still fewer reviews]

In terms of what's actually getting done, we're, uh, doing slightly better than when everyone's travelling for Christmas vacation. Part of the problem is that a ton of formerly-active reviewers are still gone; they've just been replaced by brand-new reviewers:

[image: new reviewers by week]

...and most of those new reviewers aren't doing all that many reviews, at least not yet. And chances are, a big part of the issue there is that we didn't *just* take away the text - **we also took away that number in the top bar.**

### Where and when to review

Remember, for the vast majority of reviewers the old top bar did *not* display a huge number representing all pending reviews in the system - it displayed a much smaller number representing the number of pending suggested edits.

...A smaller number that appeared *right next to* the word "review", as if to say "*n* things need your review". A good bit of the time, *n* would've been small enough that most viewers could plausibly have reviewed each item in the queue themselves, were it not for all the other folks doing the same thing.

In short, the queues *looked* much more manageable, and *were* heavily skewed in favor of driving folks to suggested edits.

By early April, we'd lost *all* of that: first we lost a lot of reviewers by removing the familiar "review" link, then we lost the focus on suggested edits by [trying to make the new UI less annoying](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/343103/help-test-the-new-top-nav-phase-3-testing-runs-this-week/343392#343392) and [more consistent](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252843/posts-awaiting-review-orange-counter-is-way-off/346653#346653).

That left us with two problems: the lack of reviewers, and the lack of anything that might tell new reviewers what was actually urgent / important.

The new "icon" - the red dot triggered by one or more queues approaching an excessively-large number of pending tasks - is an attempt to address the second problem.

Comment: I'm a bit confused. It seems like you're saying you know it's not working but you're knowingly going with a less effective solution to only half the problem.

Comment: We have no idea how effective this solution will be, @Clonkex. Hence the test. So far (about 1 day) it looks *very* effective - but that means nothing, since literally every change we've made has caused a significant bump in activity for about a week or two. Once the novelty wears off, we can see if altering the thresholds (say, dropping the bar for Suggested Edits to 90 while raising first posts & late answers) works to prioritize that queue without being overly annoying. Then... We can see how much of a problem remains. Text in the top-bar is a tough sell; gotta try everything else first.

Comment: Fair enough. _"Text in the top-bar is a tough sell"_ What people want is a tough sell? Seems like the design team might need to take a step back and reality check their priorities.

Comment: @Clonkex: "*What people want is a tough sell?*" Do people really want text in the top-bar? I certainly don't. "reviews" would be wider than the button and throw off the layout of the area.

Comment: @canon I am indeed.

Comment: Can't we just vote in some [hyperactive](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/41570?m=38637470#38637470) community designers from [ux.SE] to get the top bar fixed?

Comment: @canon I'm a little embarrassed to admit I didn't recognise the Die Hard reference without googling, but now that I know what you mean... I agree. That's what I meant by them needing to think about what their priorities are. If their goal is to make SO "look good", they're not doing their job correctly. Their job is to make a highly functional website, such that UX is at the top of the list. Once they've done that, _then_ they can make the site "look good", but "looking good" (and/or following some arbitrary/misguided goal to have everything represented by icons) should _always_ come second.

Comment: There are... rather a lot of constraints and demands on this particular bit of design. Probably more than I know of, and I know of quite a few. We're trying to provide fast access to a bunch of different functions to a bunch of different people with a bunch of different goals (some of which are not well-understood by anyone), satisfy goals for Jobs integration and (until soon) new features like Docs, branding, consistency across Int'l sites, and do all that in less space than the old header to allow it to be sticky. I don't personally *like* some of the trade-offs, but they **are** trade-offs.

Comment: This data is interesting, because it suggests a slightly different explanation for the problems than the mere change in iconography. If new users are coming to the review queues, it probably isn't the icon, since new reviewers would be the ones most affected by an inscrutable design. Veterans would only need to find it once, and would have an easier time doing so, since they knew it had to be there somewhere (because they'd used it previously). Since veterans are the ones avoiding it, that seems to indicate an active avoidance of the queues and a more deeply-rooted problem.

Comment: There's good reason to think that *everyone* found it **once**, @Cody - note the huge spike after the design change. What's been a problem has been folks finding it *again* after a week or so. Note that the same pattern that I chart above shows up for both the Site Switcher and the Achievements drop-downs, including an up-tick in late July - that's what made me skeptical about this being connected to anything specific to /review in the first place. *However*, it may be possible to mitigate the damage to review in ways that aren't possible (or necessary? I'm myopic here.) for the other tools.

Comment: I know it's not the goal of the A/B testing, but maybe now that the design team is working on this menu, it would be a good time to implement [my very simple feature request](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/346649/3764814) as well ;)

Comment: *"Ultimately, the decision of whether or not to use it or something like it rests with our design team."* There's your problem. Even looking through the comments, one senses a disconnect between those who *design* things and those of us who actually *use* things. (Back when I worked for "BigCo" we derisively call this "middle management". I almost clicked a down-vote here. But that's akin to blaming the messenger for the message. Seriously - only *designers* would have *any* issue with too much text over an icon nobody has *yet* understood.

Comment: @dfd [Voting works differently in Meta.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta) Downvoting an answer on it is nothing like shooting the messenger.

Comment: @jpmc26, I know - it's more like agree/disagree. That's actually why I didn't down vote Shog9's answer. He's merely explaining the details of something more pervasive or systemic. :-)

Comment: @CodyGray I used to review fairly consistently but took a break from SO and, when coming back, *completely forgot about the review queue because it disappeared*. I'm pretty sure I found it once when I was more active but without this post I would just keep missing the review queue button and occasionally thinking things like "did they change the rep requirements for review?" before moving on. So at least one person just missed it

Comment: My dots have just disappeared and are back to numbers for each queue. Has the experiment failed?

Comment: No... Irritatingly the groups are attached to ip + user agent not account, @stephen. So not as sticky as they should be. Expect the test to last another week.

Answer (score 26):

(Tongue planted in cheek).

This new icon and its siblings, serves a valuable purpose of hiding the review queues feature as a pale gray icon beside other pale gray icons that I'm also quite adept at completely ignoring. It's like that whole part of StackOverflow doesn't exist.

Comment: Just imagine all the bad reviewers who are now ignoring it too! With a few more tweaks, the number of active bad reviewers could be reduced to 0!

Comment: It even absorbed the Help links, too. Now we don't have to worry about pesky rules!