# Queue Icon Meaning

Tags: discussion, notifications

Every 5 minutes or so I recieve a colored Icon over the review queue:

[image]

I normally try my best to help out when I can. But this notificaiton has been popping up the past few days and everytime I click it, there are 0 posts in these three queues to look at. What is that red marker indicating? Or is this a bug?

Comment: They've been working on the false positives though, that has been an issue

Comment: @TylerH, I read through that question as well as [this one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/355236/the-new-review-icon-isnt-an-improvement) but It leaves my question still standing - *why* does this indicate? from the posts it seems like it "lights up" when queues are full - but everytime I check - they are blank

Comment: related on MSE: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/302180/review-queue-bat-signal-how-can-we-make-it-more-useful